# C# getting selected value from dropdownlist in gridview asp net

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

How can I change the value of a textbox whenever a dropdownlist within a gridview has its value changed?

On page load, the textbox shows the selected value, but when I change the selection of the dropdownlist, the textbox value doesn't change.

The code is below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Entry">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duty">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="duty" runat="server" OnLoad = "ddl1_load" OnSelectedIndexChanged="duty_SelectedIndexChanged" autopostback="true" EnableViewState="true"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The code behind is below.

```
protected void ddl1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Duty dy = new Duty();
        dt = dy.getdutyid(Convert.ToInt32(dropcontractid.SelectedValue));
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        ddl.DataSource = dt;
        ddl.DataTextField = "dutyid";
        ddl.DataValueField = "dutyid";
        ddl.DataBind();
        TextBox1.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem using the `DropDownLists` in `GridView`. My solution was to adjust the `onLoad` for the dropdown so that it wouldn't re-write the `DropDownList` on every post back. This way if there's something there then it won't re-populate it.

```
protected void dropDownLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dropDown = sender as DropDownList;
    if (dropDown.SelectedValue == null || dropDown.SelectedValue == "")
    { 
        // Your Code to populate table
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `SelectedIndexChanged` handler to show selected value:

*Markup:*

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="duty" runat="server" OnLoad="ddl1_load" OnSelectedIndexChanged="duty_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

*Code-behind:*

```
protected void duty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);   
    DropDownList duty= (DropDownList) gvr.FindControl("duty");
    TextBox1.Text = duty.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but now i am unable to get any text to show  in the textbox...

Comment: Edited the answer, place a breakpoint inside _SelectedIndexChanged_ and see what value dropdown holds.

Comment: i can only get the value on after postback, and from the breakpoint, the value is always the first selection. if i choose the second selection, it doesnt go to the textbox.

Comment: i have updated my code, it works after the adding the postback, but after i add a new line to the gridview, the dropdownlist becomes empty.... really lost here

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using data binding instead. You can bind the textbox.Text to the selecteditem.value, this will ensure that proper updating takes place

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. but im rather new to this, how do i do this??

Answer (score 0):

this happens to me once then i code like this... but i didnt use the onLoad attribute, tell me if this works,

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="duty" SortExpression="duty">
                                       <EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="duty" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("duty_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                      <ItemTemplate>
                                           <asp:Label ID="lblduty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("duty_Name") %>' />
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlduty" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownlist" 
                                          OnLoad = "ddl1_load" OnSelectedIndexChanged="duty_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible = "false" 
                                           >
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>


                                        <HeaderStyle Width="5%" />
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```